# How to stop accordion of vertical menu when child link is clicked.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I am trying to build a vertical navigation menu with accordion effect. I am almost created the menu. But the problem is all my links will be pointing to the same itself. When I clicked on any child navigation link the page will be reloaded, but the parent menu is collapsing. I want to to show the active child link highlighted even after page reload. Please suggest me to solve this problem.

Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jr6bubjb/)

html:

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
      <title>Vertical jQuery Accordion Nav Menu</title>
      <meta name="author" content="Jake Rocheleau">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://vandelaydesign.com/favicon.ico">
      <link rel="icon" href="http://vandelaydesign.com/favicon.ico">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merienda:400,700">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8" src="nav.js"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="w">
         <h1>CSS3/jQuery Accordion Nav Menu</h1>

        <nav>
            <ul id="nav">
                <li><a href="#">Animation</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Cartoons</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Comic Strips</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Video Clips</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Web GIFs</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Graphic Design</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Adobe Photoshop</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Branding &amp; Logos</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Digital Marketing</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Illustrations</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Infographics</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Product Design</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Digital Photography</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http:/www.google.com/search?q=cityscape+photography">Cityscapes</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Oceans</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Wide-Angle Lens</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Wildlife</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Print &amp; Identity</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Branding</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Business Cards</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Letterpress</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Poster Art</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Programming</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">CSS3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">HTML5</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">JavaScript &amp; jQuery</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">MySQL Databases</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Wordpress CMS</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Icons</a>
                        </li>
#">Tutorials</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">User Interfaces</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Website Layouts</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html { height: 101%; }
body { font-size: 62.5%; line-height: 1; padding-bottom: 65px; font-family: Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif; background: #c5bde5 url('images/bg.png'); }

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section { display: block; }
ol, ul { list-style: none; }

blockquote, q { quotes: none; }
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after { content: ''; content: none; }
strong { font-weight: bold; } 

table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }
img { border: 0; max-width: 100%; }

h1 { font-family: 'Merienda', 'Trebuchet MS', Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 2.95em; line-height: 1.7em; margin-bottom: 20px; font-weight: bold; letter-spacing: -0.03em; color: #675d90; text-shadow: 2px 2px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.65); text-align: center; }


#w { display: block; width: 740px; margin: 0 auto; padding-top: 45px; }


/* nav menu styles */
#nav { 
  display: block; 
  width: 280px; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  box-shadow: 3px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

#nav li { }

#nav > li > a { 
  display: block; 
  padding: 16px 18px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #d4d4d4;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #212121;
  background-color: #343434;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#343434), to(#292929));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #343434, #292929);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #343434, #292929);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #343434, #292929);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #343434, #292929);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #343434, #292929);
}
#nav > li > a:hover, #nav > li > a.open { 
  color: #e9e9e9;
  border-bottom-color: #384f76;
  background-color: #6985b5;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#6985b5), to(#456397));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6985b5, #456397);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6985b5, #456397);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #6985b5, #456397);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #6985b5, #456397);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #6985b5, #456397);
}

#nav li ul { display: none; background: #4a5b78; }

#nav li ul li a { 
  display: block; 
  background: none;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #e3e7f1;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000;
}
#nav li ul li a:hover {
  background: #394963;
}
```

Java script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#nav > li > a").on("click", function(e){
    if($(this).parent().has("ul")) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    if(!$(this).hasClass("open")) {
      // hide any open menus and remove all other classes
      $("#nav li ul").slideUp(350);
      $("#nav li a").removeClass("open");

      // open our new menu and add the open class
      $(this).next("ul").slideDown(350);
      $(this).addClass("open");
    }

    else if($(this).hasClass("open")) {
      $(this).removeClass("open");
      $(this).next("ul").slideUp(350);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the links will direct the user to a Google search page. If these are just placeholder links and you're intending on directing the user within your own site then you have many options available. Have you thought of using an AJAX technique which allows for content to be loaded without a page load? [Angular JS](https://angularjs.org/) is a great framework you can use to quickly create Single Page Applications that allow asynchronous interaction with your server.

If you require the page to be reloaded, again you have multiple options. One options is passing parameters in the request to the server which you can use to programmatically set the status of the menu.

Comment: I want to reload the page every time. I am thinking of passing a parameter through URL, but after that I have no idea how to control the parent menu.

Comment: Are you using a server side language to process the request?

Comment: I am using coldfusion language.

Comment: Check out [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubxegefh/). On the server side you can use the parameter(s) from the request to identify which menu item you need to set to the open state. I've added a piece of code which will loop any links with the open class, find the menu item that needs to be clicked, trigger a click event on that item which will open the menu.